# Qual a melhor forma de passar uma informação para a View?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
   public ActionResult AtualizaCliente(int id)
    {
        ViewBag.idFoto = new SelectList(dao.fotos, "idFoto", "Foto");
        ViewBag.idInformacao = new  SelectList(dao.informacoes, "idInformacao", "titulo");
        return View(dao.cliente.Find(id));
    }


    private string PegarCaminhoImagem(Int16 controle)
    {
        sistema_mobileEntities dao = new sistema_mobileEntities();
        dao.fotos.Find(controle);
        var caminho = dao.fotos.First().Foto;
        return caminho;
    }


    public WebImage ObterWebImage(short idFoto)
    {
        int largura = 100;
        int altura = 100;
        String caminhoFoto = PegarCaminhoImagem(idFoto);
        return new WebImage(@caminhoFoto).Resize(largura, altura, false, false);
    }


    public ActionResult AtualizaFoto(Int16 caminhofoto)
    {
        try
        {
            WebImage webImagem = ObterWebImage(caminhofoto);
            return File(webImagem.GetBytes(), "image/png");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json("A Imagem não existe : " + ex.Message);
        }

    }


    public string ObterFotoBase64(Int16 caminhofoto)
    {
        try
        {
            WebImage webImagem = ObterWebImage(caminhofoto);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(webImagem.GetBytes());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "A Imagem não existe : " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

no Controller.

Qual a melhor forma de passar o caminho da imagem para que seja visualizada?

```html
@model ProjetoDelphiMobile.Models.cliente

@{
    ViewBag.Title = ""; 
}

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#idFoto").on("change", function () {
            var srcRecebe = $($(this)).val();

            if (srcRecebe > 0) {
                $.post("@Url.Action("ObterFotoBase64", "ConsultaCliente")", { idFoto: srcRecebe }).done(function (data) {
                alert(data);
                $('#foto').attr("src", "data:image/image/png;base64," + data);
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>



<form>
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">


           <label>Foto:</label>
           <div id="selecao">
                 @Html.DropDownList("idFoto", String.Empty) 
           </div>
           <br />

          <div>
             <img id="foto" src="@Url.Action( "AtualizaFoto", "ConsultaCliente", new {caminhofoto = 1 })" alt="thumbnail" />
          </div>


           <br />

           <label>Nome:</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.nome, new { disabled = false })

           <label>Nome:</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.nome, new { disabled = false })

            <label>Nome do pai:</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.pai, new { disabled = false })

            <label>Nome da Mãe:</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.mae, new { disabled = false })

            <label>Data de Nascimento:</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.datanascimento, new { disabled = false })



        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-divider-theme="e">
            <li><a href="/ConsultaCliente">Retornar para consulta</a></li>
        </ul>

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução para o teu caso, que precisa carregar a imagem tanto com Ajax quanto com Postback, é utilizar dois métodos diferentes: um que retorna os bytes da imagem do jeito que você já estava fazendo e outro para retornar a imagem serializada em Base64. Então ficaria mais ou menos assim o código (eu adaptei para poder testar):

```
public WebImage ObterWebImage(short idFoto)
{
    int largura = 100;
    int altura = 100;
    String caminhoFoto = PegarCaminhoImagem(idFoto);
    return new WebImage(@caminhoFoto).Resize(largura, altura, false, false);
}

public ActionResult AtualizaFoto(Int16 caminhofoto)
{
    try
    {
        WebImage webImagem = ObterWebImage(caminhofoto);
        return File(webImagem.GetBytes(), "image/png");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json("A Imagem não existe : " + ex.Message);
    }

}

public string ObterFotoBase64(Int16 caminhofoto)
{
    try
    {
        WebImage webImagem = ObterWebImage(caminhofoto);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(webImagem.GetBytes());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return "A Imagem não existe : " + ex.Message;
    }
}
```

O Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#idFoto").on("change", function () {
        var srcRecebe = $($(this)).val();

        if (srcRecebe > 0) {
            $.post("@Url.Action("ObterFotoBase64", "ConsultaCliente")", { idFoto: srcRecebe }).done(function (data) {
                alert(data);
                $('#foto').attr("src", "data:image/image/png;base64," + data);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

E o Html:

```
<div>
    <img id="foto" src="@Url.Action( "AtualizaFoto", "Home", new {caminhofoto = 1 })" alt="thumbnail" />
</div>
```

**Observação:** Eu reparei que seu código tinha alguns erros:

- O segundo parâmetro do método `File` do Controller recebe o `content-type` da imagem, você estava passando o caminho;
- No resultdo do `$.post`, você estava tentando definir o atributo `src` de uma imagem com id *"#caminho"*. Pelo seu código, o id da imagem é *"#foto"*;
- O nome do seu parâmetro é "caminhoFoto" do tipo `Int16`. Não seria mais coerente chamar esse parâmetro de "idFoto"? Pois pode confundir, principalmente quando se chama o método a partir do Javascript. No seu código, no HTML da view, está passando o parâmetro `{ caminhofoto = "caminho" }` o que dá erro pois tenta converter a string "caminho" para Int16.

Comment: Aparentemente deu certo, na abertura da página chamou o AtualizaFoto, mais ao selecionar o DropDownList não está chamando o ObterFotoBase64, eu alterei todo o código para ficar igual ao que passou, consegue me ajudar?

Comment: O evento `change` do dropDown está sendo disparado? Se sim, encontrei uma diferença no nome do controller no meu código. Eu testei usando um controller chamado `HomeController`, mas o seu controller chama `ConsultaClienteController`. Então a linha do `$.post` deveria ser  `$.post("@Url.Action("ObterFotoBase64", "ConsultaCliente")"`. Verifique se o seu código não ficou usando `HomeController` com estava antes na minha resposta.

Comment: Na minha pergunta, eu alterei todo o código de acordo com o ajuste que fiz, $.post("@Url.Action("ObterFotoBase64", "ConsultaCliente")",

Comment: O evento change do dropDown está sendo disparado? O método `ObterFotoBase64` do controller está sendo chamado? Está retornando? O jQuery caiu no evento `done`? Por favor, você precisa especificar o que está dando erro, faça um debug e nos diga.

Comment: O método ObterFotoBase64 não está sendo chamado! agradeço!